# Affine Transforming Coordinate Set in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, affinetransform

In OpenCV, I can [affine transform an image using](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html):

```
M = np.float32(...)
array_tform = cv2.warpAffine(arr, M, (cols, row))
```

this works if the image is represented as bitmap.

What about if the "image" is instead represented as a set of points (coordinates)? i.e. I want to perform the affine transformation on a set of points. For example, translate by `(+1,+1)`:

```
{ (1, 2), (3, 4) } --> { (2, 3), (4, 5) }
```

Is there a way to affine transform a point set?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [transform()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transform) function. It can by used for a lot of different things, but the most basic use is applying affine transformation to every point in array.